# Understanding mathematics in derivation of vector form of Snell's law

Tags: vectors, physics

I am currently studying [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/436252/141502) answer on physics.stackexchange to a [question on the vector form of Snell's law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/435512/141502). The answer (by the user [Frobenius](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/227119/frobenius)) proceeds as follows:

> Let a unit vector $\;\mathbf{n} = (\rm n_1,n_2,n_3)\,, \Vert\mathbf{n}\Vert = 1$. Any vector $\;\mathbf{r}\;$ could be decomposed in two components with respect to $\;\mathbf{n}\;$, see Figure-01 in the bottom
> \begin{equation}
>    \mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_\|+\mathbf{r}_\bot
>    \tag{01}\label{01}
> \end{equation}
> one parallel and the other normal to axis $\mathbf{n}$ respectively
> \begin{align}
>    \mathbf{r}_\| &=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r}\right)\mathbf{n}
>    \tag{02.1}\label{02.1}\\
>    \mathbf{r}_\bot &=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{r}\right)\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{n}= \mathbf{r}-(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r})\mathbf{n}
>    \tag{02.2}\label{02.2}
> \end{align}
> that is
> \begin{equation}
>    \mathbf{r}=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{r}\right)\mathbf{n}+\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{r}\right)\boldsymbol{\times} \mathbf{n}
>    \tag{03}\label{03}
> \end{equation}
> The vectors $\;\mathbf{t},\mathbf{i}\;$ are decomposed as follows
> \begin{equation}
>    \mathbf{t}=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)\mathbf{n}+\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{t}\right)\boldsymbol{\times} \mathbf{n}
>    \tag{04}\label{04}
> \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}
>    \mathbf{i}=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}+\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{i}\right)\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{n}
>    \tag{05}\label{05}
> \end{equation}
> Now, Snell's Law is expressed as
> \begin{equation}
>   \left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{t}\right)=\mu\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{i}\right)
>    \tag{06}\label{06}
> \end{equation}
> see Figure-02 in the bottom.
> Equation \eqref{04} combined with \eqref{05} and \eqref{06} yields
> \begin{equation}
>    \mathbf{t}=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)\mathbf{n}+\mu\left[\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\right]
>    \tag{07}\label{07}
> \end{equation}
> Taking norms in \eqref{07} and since the vector $\;\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)\mathbf{n}\;$ is normal to the vector $\;\left[\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\right]\;$
> \begin{equation}
>    \Vert\mathbf{t}\Vert^2=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)^2+\mu^2\Vert\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\Vert^2
>    \tag{08}\label{08}
> \end{equation}
> or
> \begin{equation}
>    1=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)^2+\mu^2\left[1-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)^2\right]
>    \tag{09}\label{09}
> \end{equation}
> so
> \begin{equation}
>    \left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)=\pm\sqrt{1-\mu^2\left[1-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)^2\right]}
>    \tag{10}\label{10} 
> \end{equation}
> Since the angle between $\;\mathbf{n},\mathbf{t}\;$ is less than $\;\pi/2\;$ we keep the plus sign in \eqref{10} and \eqref{07} yields finally
> \begin{equation}
>    \mathbf{t}=\sqrt{1-\mu^2\left[1-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)^2\right]}\mathbf{n}+\mu\left[\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\right]
>    \tag{11}\label{11}
> \end{equation}
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

How does the author get (08) and (09)?
For $\Vert\mathbf{t}\Vert^2=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)^2+\mu^2\Vert\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\Vert^2$, what happened to the $\mathbf{n}$ in $\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)\mathbf{n}$? Shouldn't it be $\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)^2 \mathbf{n}^2$?

Comment: Just want to advise that you should ask these questions on Reddit in subs like r/calculus or r/askmath , you will receive various answers very quickly and Reddit mods are unlikely to remove your posts for no reason (unlike Stackexchange mods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's begin with $(7)$ which reads

$$\mathbf{t}=\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)\mathbf{n}+\mu\left[\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\right]\tag1$$

Then, expressing the square of the magnitude of $\mathbf{t}$, $\Vert\mathbf{t}\Vert^2$ by $\mathbf{t}\cdot \mathbf{t}$, we have from $(1)$

$$\Vert\mathbf{t}\Vert^2=\left(\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)\mathbf{n}+\mu\left[\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\right]\right)\cdot \left(\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{t}\right)\mathbf{n}+\mu\left[\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\right]\right)\tag2$$

Next, since $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector, then $\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{n}=1$.

And since the term in brackets in $(2)$, $\left[\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\right]$, is perpendicular to $\mathbf{n}$, we immediately have from $(2)$

$$\Vert\mathbf{t}\Vert^2=(\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{t})^2+\mu^2\Vert\mathbf{\left[\mathbf{i}-\left(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{i}\right)\mathbf{n}\right]}\Vert^2\tag3$$

Note that $(3)$ is identical to $(9)$ in the OP.  And we are done!

Comment: Thanks again!!!