# Understanding mathematics in derivation of vector form of the law of refraction

Tags: vectors, physics

I am currently studying [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/650685/141502) answer on physics.stackexchange to a [question I asked on the law of refraction in vector form](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/650655/141502). The answer (by the user [JEB](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/82339/jeb)) proceeds as follows:

> Given two vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, the vector projection of $\vec a$ onto $\vec b$ is:
>
> $$\vec a_{\parallel \vec b}=
> \frac{\vec a \cdot \vec b}{\vec b \cdot \vec b}
> \vec b$$
>
> The component of $\vec a$ that is perpendicular to this is called the vector rejection on $\hat b$:
>
> $$ \vec a_{\perp \vec b}=\vec a - \vec a_{\parallel \vec b}=\vec a -
> \frac{\vec a \cdot \vec b}{\vec b \cdot \vec b}
> $$
>
> If $\vec b=\hat b$ is a unit vector:
>
> $$ \vec a_{\perp \vec b}=\vec a -(\vec a\cdot \hat b)\hat b$$

How is it that $\vec a -(\vec a\cdot \hat b)\hat b = \vec a - \frac{\vec a \cdot \vec b}{\vec b \cdot \vec b}$? If we say that $\vec b = \hat b$, then we have $\vec a - \frac{\vec a \cdot \hat b}{\hat b \cdot \hat b}$, but I don't see how that is $\vec a -(\vec a\cdot \hat b)\hat b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an obvious typographical error.  Note that $\frac{\vec a\cdot \vec b}{\vec b\cdot \vec b}$ is a scalar, not a vector, while $(\vec a\cdot \hat b)\hat b$ is a vector that is parallel to $\vec b$.

Instead, using $\hat b=\frac{\vec b}{|\vec b|}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(\vec a\cdot \hat b)\hat b&=\left(\vec a\cdot \frac{\vec b}{|\vec b|}\right)\frac{\vec b}{|\vec b|}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{\vec a\cdot \vec b}{|\vec b|^2}\right) \vec b\\\\
&=\left(\frac{\vec a\cdot \vec b}{\vec b\cdot \vec b}\right) \vec b\\\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank *you* for taking the time to answer! :) Any chance you could have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4195833/356308 (similar) question I just asked? It hasn't had any answers yet.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I've just posted a solution to the referenced question.